# How to call UIView transition on a UIButton image from outside the button?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uibutton

I'm looking to call this `UIView` transition from both inside and outside of the button. Whenever I try anything other than `sender` after `with:` I get `Cannot convert vale to....` errors. Is there a way to achieve this?  Thanks!

```
@IBOutlet weak var someButton: UIButton!       
@IBAction func someButton(_ sender: UIButton) {

UIView.transition(with: sender, duration: 0.3, options: .transitionCrossDissolve, animations: {
    sender.setImage(UIImage(named: "My Image.png"), for: UIControl.State.highlighted)
}, completion: nil)

//...other functions

}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking.   Can you add the entire error message that you are getting and show where in your code that error occurs?

Comment: Thanks for asking @ScottThompson !  When I was looking into more specific cases to demonstrate the error I figured out the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Make it a function like this

```
func animation(sender: UIButton){
    UIView.transition(with: sender, duration: 0.3, options: .transitionCrossDissolve, animations: {
        sender.setImage(UIImage(named: "image.png"), for: .highlighted)
    }, completion: nil)
}
```

Call it from the tap of the button or any other location like so:

```
animation(sender: sender)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make transition of `UIButton` with firebase call or some other event action by creating a separate function like shown below. Use the `UIButton`'s `outlet` to access the button.

```
@IBOutlet weak var someButton: UIButton!

func buttonTransition() {

    UIView.transition(with: sender, duration: 0.3, options: .transitionCrossDissolve, animations: {
        someButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "My Image.png"), for: UIControl.State.highlighted)
    }, completion: nil)
}
```

So, you can call `buttonTransition()` function from wherever you want.

Answer (score -1):

I figured it out; I wasn't using the ViewController name when assigning `with:` to the UIButton:

```
UIView.transition(with: ViewController().buttonName,....
```